# Generate files in shell script

Tags: shell

How I can generate 100 files in format `Test1YYYYMMDDHHMM1.txt`, `Test1YYYYMMDDHHMM2.txt`, `Test1YYYYMMDDHHMM3.txt`, ..., `Test1YYYYMMDDHHMM100.txt`? This files was write in directory which is variable in the shell script.

Comment: What shell are you using to write your script, and what have you tried so far?  What should happen if a file or directory already exists with one of those names (for example, if you ran the script twice in a row)?

Comment: Bash: `touch Test1YYYYMMDDHHMM{1..100}.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir Test1$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M){1..100}
touch Test1$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M){1..100}.txt
```

This will create 100 directories see the man page for date and and also check brace expansion in bash.  These are the things your working with here.

The `touch` command will do the same but will create files.

These ideas can be used across a variety of commands in bash and come to the rescue in all kinds of ways it is something you should really take the time to learn and understand

Comment: You assume that OP is using Bash.

Comment: Yes I assume there using by far the most popular shell.

Answer (score 4):

To portably create the files that you require, and assuming that `YYYYMMDDHHMM` should be the current year, month, day, hour, and minute, you would use a loop in the shell:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

destdir=${1:-.}

cd "$destdir" || exit 1

now=$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M )

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 100 ]; do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    touch "Test1$now$i.txt"
done
```

The `cd "$destdir" || exit 1` would change the current directory to whatever directory path `$destdir` refers to, or terminate the script if that was not possible.  The `destdir` variable takes its value from the first argument on the script's command line, or, if no argument is given, will be `.`, i.e. the current directory.  To create the files in `~/somedir` you would run this script as `./script ~/somedir`.

This first sets the value of `now` to be the string representation of the timestamp that you need.  It then loops 100 times and creates your files using the `touch` command, with the timestamp and the counter variable `i`.

---

In the `bash` shell, you would probably want to use a brace expansion to replace the loop above.  This is doable as long as the total length of the generate command line is not too long.  If it becomes too long, which it would not be for 100 files, you would get an "argument list too long" error, and you would have to resort to something like the loop above.

You can also use the special `%(...)T` format string with the built-in `printf` utility in `bash`, instead of calling the `date` utility.  This requires `bash` release 4.2 or later.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

destdir=${1:-.}

cd "$destdir" || exit 1

printf -v now '%(%Y%m%d%H%M)T' -1

touch "Test1$now"{1..100}.txt
```

If you need to create *many thousands* of files, which the above code does not allow you to do, and if you *really dislike* loops (or just like writing unreadable and unmaintainable code), then the `xargs` command may help you:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

destdir=${1:-.}

cd "$destdir" || exit 1

printf -v now '%(%Y%m%d%H%M)T' -1

printf 'Test1%s.txt\n' "$now"{1..100} | xargs touch
```

This would call the `touch` utility via `xargs`, which would read the arguments from `printf` and would create the files in manageable batches instead of all at once.  There would be no issues calling the `printf` utility with all the filenames since `printf` is a built-in utility.

---

In the `zsh` shell, if you wanted to be different, you might possibly do something like

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

destdir=${1:-.}

cd $destdir || exit 1

zmodload zsh/datetime

strftime -s now %Y%m%d%H%M

i=0
repeat 100 touch Test1$now$((++i)).txt
```

You can obviously use ordinary brace expansion with `zsh` as well, but the above shows how to use the simplified variant of `zsh`'s `repeat` loop.

Comment: Now, how can I make it change to read from a conf.txt. And to know how many files we need to create and in which directory we need to write them.

Comment: @User231 The question does not say anything about this.  You may want to ask a new question where you make the requirements a bit more explicit.

Comment: I want to create shell script which is read from conf.txt. The same script should return the contents of the conf file, the number and files and the directory where it is written.